# Do we have any ways to retrieve the list of process and threads which are in runnable state(not running state) in ubuntu?

Tags: c, multithreading, ubuntu, rtos, cpuset

My requirement is to do dynamic cpu shielding in C program based on the queue length of runnable threads (but not running threads which are waiting for CPU availability) in Realtime operating systems-(say ubuntu with RT linux patch) scenarios. For example, we can consider the system is configured for SCHED_FIFO policy.

I am not able to find any commands to retrieve the number of process which are in wait state, running state, runnable state etc.

Any help is much appreciated.

The command 'PS -T au' shows the state of all 'runnable' as well as 'running' threads as 'R'.

```
PS -T au
```

Below is the result I am getting from above command. In this ThreadID-16841, 16842 and 16843 are threads which were created by main process 16840. All the above created threads were showing in R state which denotes Runnable or running.

Instead I would like a linux command or C API to retrieve the number of processes in a runnable state but not running.

```
USER       PID  SPID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

root       914   914  0.1  1.3 428324 105804 tty7    Rsl+ Oct23   1:27 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten

root       914   925  0.0  1.3 428324 105804 tty7    Ssl+ Oct23   0:04 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -core :0 -seat seat0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -nolisten

root      1170  1170  0.0  0.0  23004  1772 tty1     Ss+  Oct23   0:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux

senthil   1979  1979  0.0  0.0  29532  5056 pts/11   Ss   Oct23   0:00 bash

senthil   2032  2032  0.0  0.0  29552  5212 pts/2    Ss   Oct23   0:00 bash

root     16837 16837  0.0  0.0  62092  4132 pts/2    S+   09:37   0:00 sudo ./sigmain

root     16840 16840  0.0  0.0  31108   796 pts/2    Sl+  09:37   0:00 ./sigmain

root     16840 16841 95.9  0.0  31108   796 pts/2    Rl+  09:37   9:01 ./sigmain

root     16840 16842 95.9  0.0  31108   796 pts/2    Rl+  09:37   9:01 ./sigmain

root     16840 16843 95.9  0.0  31108   796 pts/2    Rl+  09:37   9:01 ./sigmain

senthil  17225 17225  0.0  0.0  44432  3364 pts/11   R+   09:46   0:00 ps -T au
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423500/how-to-get-the-number-of-processes-waiting-for-cpu-on-linux

Comment: The information obtained from /proc/stat does not give process nice value or thread priority in straight forward manner. Do we have any other ways other than this?